Pythonerror when working with asyncio, aiosqlite and telethon
My code:

from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
import asyncio
import aiosqlite

api_id = 111111
api_hash = "sksk9449"

client = TelegramClient("main_session", api_id, api_hash)

bot_id = 12345
chat_id = -1234567

async def aiosqlite_connect_db():
    return await aiosqlite.connect("DataBase.db")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chat_id))
async def normal_handler(event):
    user_id = event.message.to_dict()['from_id']['user_id']
    if user_id == bot_id:
        print(True)

client.start()

db = asyncio.run(aiosqlite_connect_db())

client.run_until_disconnected()

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 430, in get_running_loop

    return asyncio.get_running_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

RuntimeError: no running event loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)

  File "<string>", line 27, in <module>

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py", line 93, in run_until_disconnected

    if self.loop.is_running():
       ^^^^^^^^^

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 487, in loop

    return helpers.get_running_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 432, in get_running_loop

    return asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 677, in get_event_loop

    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.

I changed some of the information in the code to a random set of numbers and letters.
As I think the problem is with asyncio
How can I solve this problem? Is it worth using asyncio for launching asynchronous functions , or are there other ways?
I tried creating and installing new streams, but it didn't help.

The issue is related to how asyncio.run() is being used with Telethon's event loop. Telethon already manages its own event loop, and using asyncio.run() in the same thread can cause conflicts. Instead you should use Telethon's event loop like this:
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
import aiosqlite

api_id = 111111
api_hash = "sksk9449"

client = TelegramClient("main_session", api_id, api_hash)

bot_id = 12345
chat_id = -1234567

async def aiosqlite_connect_db():
    return await aiosqlite.connect("DataBase.db")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chat_id))
async def normal_handler(event):
    user_id = event.message.to_dict()['from_id']['user_id']
    if user_id == bot_id:
        print(True)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    db = await aiosqlite_connect_db()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

asyncio.run(main())

